# what measures you look at the determine over fitting in linear regression?

Tags: regression, self-study

> Which of the following is NOT a valid measure of overfitting?
>
> - Sum of parameters $\left(w_1+w_2+\ldots+w_n\right)$
> - Sum of squares of parameters $\left(w_1^2 + w_2^2 + \ldots +w_n^2\right)$
> - Range of parameters, i.e., difference between maximum and minimum parameters
> - Sum of absolute values of parameters $\left(|w_1| + |w_2| + \ldots + |w_n|\right)$

Can somebody try to explain this to me?

Comment: Given that the parameters in a model literally could have any value, in what sense could you possibly conceive of *any* of these as being a measure of *anything*? Is this question perhaps extracted from a context in which a specific model is under consideration and its parameters have somehow been standardized?

Comment: linear regression model.

Comment: I think that whuber is saying that without more context (ie, assuming only the $w_i$ are the parameters of a linear regression model fit on any data), we can't hope to interpret the $w_i$ meaningfully. Is this related to linear regression on data in any particular domain?

Comment: Hint: putting aside for now the issue of whether any of these is a measure of overfitting, consider how these various measures would behave if some parameter values were negative and others were positive.

Comment: Are you asking this question in the context of linear model regularization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, let me describe the meaning of over-fitting in general. Overfitting means your model not only fits the relationship between the dependent variables and independent variable, but also fits random noise into it. Here is a good example of underfitting, right fitting and overfitting.  [image]

Fitting such a over fitting model will result in a very low error in predicting your training data (or you can image that you are using the model fitted by the data to predict the same data, of cause the more complex the model the lower the error) but a very high error when you predict NEW data (testing data). Error can be defined as $\sum(\hat{y} - y)^2$, where $\hat{y}$ is fitted value.

In general, I don't think any of the methods you mentioned in your question would help you to prevent or detect over-fitting in a linear regression model.

For example, if you are fitting a linear model between the area of house (Y, in $m^2$) and the price of the house (X, in $k$ dollars). The model is like

$Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon,$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

Then, for example, the sum of parameter is
$\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta} + \hat{\sigma}$, if I understand your question correctly.

However, if you change the unit of price of the house from $k$ dollars to million dollars, your $\hat{\beta}$ will change to $\hat{\beta}/1000$. Thus the sum of the parameter reduce to $\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta}/1000 + \hat{\sigma}$. But you cannot say either of the model is more over-fitting than the other one even the sum of parameters changes.

What I usually use to prevent over-fitting is [cross validation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eschneide/tut5/node42.html). Cross validation means that you split your data into several subsets. For each subset, you use it as testing set while using others as training set to fit a model and use it to predict the testing set and calculate the prediction error for this testing set. Then you average your prediction errors among all the testing set, you'll get a cross validation error.

Or for simple cases, I would use [adjusted $R^2$](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-R-squared-and-Adjusted-R-squared) from the output of `lm` in r.  Adjusted $R^2$ takes into the complexity of your model into account. Complexity will tend to reduce the adjusted $R^2$.

Comment: Note that this is a self-study question and should be answered accordingly...

Comment: @Richard Hardy, what do you mean? Without knowing the field of study, I don't think the four ways of combination of $\omega$'s can be related to overfitting.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of the `self-study` tag? An answer should help the asker gradually progress with his/her own thinking. See more [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Oh, thanks. I am new to cross validated. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: If you are new then -- warm welcome to CV!

Comment: It's a very good answer.  Thank you for continuing to improve it!